# Symfony 3 - Outsourcing Controller Code into Service Layer

Tags: php, dependency-injection, doctrine-orm, symfony

I am very new in Symfony 3 and I want to avoid
the business logic in my controllers.
What I have done so far is this:

```
    <?php

    namespace RestBundle\Controller;

    use RestBundle\Entity\Attribute;
    use RestBundle\Entity\DistributorProduct;
    use RestBundle\Entity\AttributeValue;
    use RestBundle\Entity\ProductToImage;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use RestBundle\Entity\Product;
    use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;


        /**
         * Product controller.
         *
         */
        class ProductController extends FOSRestController
        {

                /**
                 * Creates a new Product entity.
                 *
                 */
                public function createProductAction(Request $request)
                {
                    // Doctrine Manager
                    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

                    // todo: get the logged in distributor object
                    $distributor = $em->getRepository('RestBundle:Distributor')->find(1);

                    // Main Product
                    $product = new Product();
                    $product->setEan($request->get('ean'));
                    $product->setAsin($request->get('asin'));
                    $em->persist($product);

                    // New Distributor Product
                    $distributorProduct = new DistributorProduct();
                    $distributorProduct->setDTitle($request->get('title'));
                    $distributorProduct->setDDescription($request->get('description'));
                    $distributorProduct->setDPrice($request->get('price'));
                    $distributorProduct->setDProductId($request->get('product_id'));
                    $distributorProduct->setDStock($request->get('stock'));
                    // Relate this distributorProduct to the distributor
                    $distributorProduct->setDistributor($distributor);
                    // Relate this distributorProduct to the product
                    $distributorProduct->setProduct($product);
                    $em->persist($distributorProduct);

                    // Save it
                    $em->flush();

                    $response = $em->getRepository('RestBundle:Product')->find($product->getUuid());

                    return array('product' => $response);
                }
            }
        }
```

I know that this is not good code because all the business logic is in the controller.

But how and where can I put this code (set requests into model, persist and flush with doctrine, etc) into a service or use dependency injection for it? Or is service for this purpose not the right way?

I know this page and tutorial http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/business-logic.html
but it is not clearify for me where to put CRUD Actions. 
Do ONE service for save a whole project with all the related entities? And use the  Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request; in a service? So put the whole controller code where I get the request and assign to the models into a service?
Thanks

Comment: If you are using some sort of form to create product, then using Symfony forms would automatically map form data to your entity data: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html

Comment: Put in separate service and inject entity manager in it

Comment: no, I am using only an API so no view. Only receive POST data, assign to different entities, save it, and response the saved product.

Comment: Ok but what is best practise for the service? Do ONE service for save a whole project with all the related entities? And use the  Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request; in a service? So put the whole controller code where I get the request and assign to the models into a service?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**UPDATE 2: [I've extended this answer in a post](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/10/16/how-to-use-repository-with-doctrine-as-service-in-symfony/). Be sure to check it!**

**UPDATE: use Symfony 3.3 (May 2017) with [PSR-4 service autodiscovery](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/05/07/how-to-refactor-to-new-dependency-injection-features-in-symfony-3-3/#4-use-psr-4-based-service-autodiscovery-and-registration)** and PHP 7.1 types.

---

I will show you how I lecture **controller repository decoupling** in companies.

There are 2 simple rules:

- there are no signs about Doctrine in controller
- there is no `new` in the controller (static, non-DI approach) ([there is now also Sniff for that](https://github.com/Symplify/CodingStandard#use-service-and-constructor-injection-rather-than-instantiation-with-new))

## Let's apply this to your controller

*Note: this is pseudo code, I haven't tried that, but the logic should be  easy to understand. If this is too many change, just check the steps 3 and 4.*

We decouple create and save process. For both entities.
This will lead us to 4 services:

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    _defaults:  
        autowire: true

    App\Domain\:
        resource: ../../App/Domain
    App\Repository\:
        resource: ../../App/Repository
```

### 1. Product Factory to decouple create process

```
// ProductFactory.php
namespace App\Domain\Product;

final class ProductFactory
{
    public function createFromRequest(Request $request): Product
    {
        $product = new Product();
        $product->setEan($request->get('ean'));
        $product->setAsin($request->get('asin'));
        return $product;
    }
}
```

### 2. Distributor Product Factory to decouple create process

```
// DistributorProductFactory.php
namespace App\Domain\Product;

final class DistributorProductFactory
{
    public function createFromRequestProductAndDistributor(
        Request $request,
        Product $product,
        Distributor $distributor
    ): DistributorProduct {
        $distributorProduct = new DistributorProduct();
        $distributorProduct->setDTitle($request->get('title'));
        $distributorProduct->setDDescription($request->get('description'));
        $distributorProduct->setDPrice($request->get('price'));
        $distributorProduct->setDProductId($request->get('product_id'));
        $distributorProduct->setDStock($request->get('stock'));

        // Relate this distributorProduct to the product
        $distributorProduct->setProduct($product);

        // Relate this distributorProduct to the product
        $distributorProduct->setDistributor($distributor);

        return $distributorProduct;
    }
}
```

### 3. Create own ProductRepository service

```
// ProductRepository.php
namespace App\Repository;

use RestBundle\Entity\Product;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

final class ProductRepository
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private $entityManager;

    public funtion __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)    
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function save(Product $product): void
    {
        $this->entityManager->persist($product);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
    }
}
```

### 4. Create own DistributorProductRepository service

```
// DistributorProductRepository.php
namespace App\Repository;

use RestBundle\Entity\DistributorProduct;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

final class DistributorProductRepository
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private $entityManager;

    public funtion __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)    
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function save(DistributorProduct $distributorProduct): void
    {
        $this->entityManager->persist($distributorProduct);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
    }
}
```

### 5. And we finish with nice and thin controller!

```
namespace RestBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;

final class ProductController extends FOSRestController
{
    // get here dependencies via constructor

    public function createProductAction(Request $request): array
    {
        // todo: get the logged in distributor object
        $distributor = $em->getRepository('RestBundle:Distributor')->find(1);

        $product = $this->productFactory->createFromRequest($request);
        $distributorProduct = $this->distributorProductFactory->createFromRequestProductAndDistributor(
            $request,
            $product,
            $distributor
        );

        $this->productRepository->save($product);
        $this->distributorProductRepository->save($product);

        return [
            'product' => $product
        ];
    }
}
```

That's all!

Comment: wow nice answer, thanks! I will create the factories and repositories and I will check how it works! After that and it is work I will accept your answer. thank you so much to push me into the right direction!

Comment: there is an error if I use this with the factories and repositories: Type error: Argument 1 passed to RestBundle\\Repository\\ProductRepository::__construct() must implement interface Doctrine\\ORM\\EntityManagerInterface, none given, called in /var/www/var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 2729", ... I fix it with the arguments parameter in my services.yml: product_repository:
        class: RestBundle\Repository\ProductRepository
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]

Comment: Your solution works, but it removes very helpful autowiring feature.
To use this, I recommend adding https://github.com/Symplify/ControllerAutowire bundle and https://github.com/Symplify/DefaultAutowire

But it not needed. I'm glad you liked it and that it works :) good job!

Comment: And if you need to update the data how you should handle it using the factory class ? Also how initial empty fields should be handled ?