# Symfony3: Service not able to get arguments

Tags: service, dependency-injection, model, doctrine, symfony

I have made a service to get Doctrine connection in my models (Not sure if it is a nice approach but I dont want to pass connection from controller to model constructor each time).

So lets say I want products in my controller

```
public function getProductsAction(Request $request) {
    $product_model = new ProductModel();
    return $product_model->getProducts();
}
```

I have Product model Which will access a helper to get "database_connection"

```
use AppBundle\Helper\ContainerHelper;

class ProductModel {
    function getProducts() {
        $helper = new ContainerHelper();
        $db = $helper->getDoctrine();

        $query = "SELECT * FROM customer_products;";
        $statement = $db->prepare($query);

        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Now this helper is defined in src/AppBundle/Helper/ContainerHelper.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Helper;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface as Container;

class ContainerHelper {

    private $container;

    public function __construct(Container $container) {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public static function getDoctrine() {
        $database_connection = $this->container->get('database_connection');
        return $database_connection;
    }

}
```

Lets say this service needs "service container" so in app/config/services.yml

```
services:
    app.container_helper:
        class: AppBundle\Helper\ContainerHelper
        arguments: ['@service_container']
```

But it gives me error:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   AppBundle\Helper\ContainerHelper::__construct() must implement
>   interface Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface,
>   none given, called in \src\AppBundle\Model\ProductModel.php
>   on line 148 and defined

While I believe that I have implemented it correctly according to http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html and http://anjanasilva.com/blog/injecting-services-in-symfony-2/, its certain that I have missed something or just got the whole bad idea. I need to know if it is a correct concept or what I have missed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While @pavlovich is trying to fix your existing code, I really think you are making this much more convoluted than it has to be.  ProductModel itself should be a service with your database connection injected into it.

```
class ProductModel {
    public function __construct($conn) {
        $this->conn = $conn;
    }
    public function getProducts() {
        $stmt = $this->conn->executeQuery('SELECT * FROM customer_products');
        return $stmt->fetchAll();
   }

services:
    product_model:
        class: AppBundle\...\ProductModel
        arguments: ['@database_connection']

// controller.php
$productModel = $this->get('product_model'); // Pull from container
$products = $productModel->getProducts();
```

Comment: Thanks for quick help. . I knew I was something missing. Extra helper layer is there to avoid injection into all models. I will have to define same injection for all models in service.yml. Is there any other possible work-around like other frameworks they extend base model and thus they get DB connection automatically, because more models I have, service.yml will be filled with same repeated thing.

Comment: Take a look at parent services: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parentservices.html By the way, use something like @Cerad when replying to a specific comment so the person will get a notification.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using helpers, I'd recommend using **constructor injection and autowiring**. It's more safe, future proof and easier to extend and test.

In such case, you'd have to create `ProductRepository` (more common and standard name for `ProductModel`) and pass it to controller.

#### 1. Controller

```
<?php

class SomeController
{
    /**
     * @var ProductRepository
     */
    private $productRepository;

    public function __construct(ProductRepository $productRepository)
    {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    public function getProductsAction()
    {
        return $this->productRepository->getProducts();
    }
}
```

If you have difficulties to register controller as a service, just use [Symplify\ControllerAutowire bundle](https://github.com/symplify/ControllerAutowire).

#### 2. ProductRepository

```
// src/AppBundle/Repository/ProductRepository.php

namespace AppBundle\Repository;

class ProductRepository
{
    /**
     * @var Doctrine\DBAL\Connection
     */
    private $connection;

    public function __construct(Doctrine\DBAL\Connection $connection)
    {

        $this->connection = $connection;
    }

    public function fetchAll()
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM customer_products;";

        $statement = $this->connection->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute();
        return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
}
```

#### 3. Service registration

```
# app/cofig/servies.yml

services:
    product_repository:
        class: AppBundle\Repository\ProductRepository
        autowire: true
```

For more you can see similar question with answer here: [Symfony 3 - Outsourcing Controller Code into Service Layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38346281/symfony-3-outsourcing-controller-code-into-service-layer/38349271#38349271)

Comment: This is also a very nice and clean approach. . but not feasible all the time. Suppose I need products in customer controller. Also need orders, vouchers and many other things. Not a very good idea to auto-wire all these repositories on constructor, I suppose

Comment: Why? Many dependencies should lead to decoupling and architecture improvemets. Having around 5 dependencies is usually fine.  Over 10 is an alarm to do something.

Answer (score 1):

With new version of Symfony 3.3, a new feature is added (Auto-wired Services Dependencies)

https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html
https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html

Using this feature, I solved this issue in following way:

1. Added a new directory /src/AppBundle/Model
2. Added my model classes in this directory

   ```
   namespace AppBundle\Modal;

   use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

   class ProductModal
   {

      private $em;

      // We need to inject this variables later.
      public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
      {
          $this->em = $entityManager;
      }

      // We need to inject this variables later.
      public function getProducts()
      {
          $statement = $this->em->getConnection()->prepare("SELECT * FROM product WHERE 1");
          $statement->execute();
          $results = $statement->fetchAll();

          return $results;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Added in my app/config/services.yml

   ```
   AppBundle\Modal\:
      resource: '../../src/AppBundle/Modal/*'
      public: true
   ```
4. In my controller I can use it like

   ```
   $products = $this->get(ProductModal::class)->getProducts();
   ```

**P.S.** Dont forget to add `use AppBundle\Entity\Product\Product;` in controller